# Is it possible to use an in-memory SQLite database when testing Flask with Peewee ORM?

Tags: flask, pytest, peewee

I'm writing tests to my Flask web application and while trying to test an endpoint that interacts with the database I encountered an error.

My `client` fixture tries to follow the spirit of [Flask's testing tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/testing/#the-testing-skeleton):

```py
DATABASE = {
    "engine": "SqliteDatabase",
    "name": ":memory:",
}


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    app = create_app({"TESTING": True, "DATABASE": DATABASE})
    with app.test_client() as client:
        with app.app_context():
            db_wrapper.init_app(app)
            init_database()
        yield client
```

But when trying to run the simplest test,

```py
def test_test_endpoint(client):
    client.post("/test")
```

I'm getting `peewee.OperationalError: Connection already opened.`

I already know that `db_wrapper` opens a connection when I call `init_database`, and that `connect_db` is called by Flask's `preprocess_request` that was set by `FlaskDB` wrapper.

For the sake of testing, even though it will erase all the data in my SQLite in-memory database, I tried to call `db_wrapper.database.close()` after `init_database`, but got the same error, so even if having an in-memory test database isn't ideal, it seems like my problem wouldn't be resolved by moving the data to the disk.

Comment: What is `db_wrapper`? What does `db_wrapper.init_app()` do? Are you installing request hooks that open/close the db on each request? In-memory db only live as long as the connection, so you will have to ensure you do not close it during tests.

Comment: hi @coleifer! thanks for responding, I love your project! `db_wrapper` is an instance of `FlaskDB`. I went over and read the code in `playhouse/flask_utils.py` and I know that upon calling `db_wrapper.init_app()`  it internally calls `_register_handlers(app)` which installs hooks to open/close the database connection. Is the situation you're describing, "so you will have to ensure you do not close it during tests" even possible while using `FlaskDB` wrapper? I mean, `init_database` which internally calls `create_tables` already opens the database, and closing the connection means data is gone.

Answer (score 1):

After talking with @coleifer over peewee's IRC channel (#peewee @ libera.chat) the conclusion is that there are two options,

1. Subclass `FlaskDB` and stop it from registering the request handlers at `_register_handlers(app)`
2. Use a `tempfile`

The reason is that SQLite `:memory:` mode is a special mode where each time the connection is dropped, the data is lost, and one of the features of `FlaskDB` is that it takes care of creating and terminating the connection to the database before and after each request.